# WPF - DisplayMemberPath of nested property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I've a combobox with ItemsSource property bound to my ICollectionView of City type.

In turn, City contains an Address property which contains AddressNameString.

I would be able to set as DispalyMemberPath AddressNameString property, however it seems impossible to achieve.

Isn't it? Is there some workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting the `DisplayMemberPath` to a nested property path should work:

```
DisplayMemberPath="Address.AddressNameString"
```

You could also use the `ItemTemplate` property instead of the `DisplayMemberPath` property:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address.AddressNameString}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Make sure that the property is public and that you haven't misspelled the property name in your XAML.

Comment: Then you have probably misspelled the property names. Please post your class definitions.

Comment: It was my mistake. You are right. Thank you very much.